# HLM vs linear mixed models vs random effects model

Tags: multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

would anyone please tell me the differences among the three methods? 
also i have a data in which the dependent variable is a count variable. is it classified as a level 1 variable? one of my classmates tried using HLM, and he clustered the DV into groups. Im not really familiar with hierarchical modeling. so i would really appreciate if someone could help me with this one?

Comment: I think they're all just different names for the same thing. You can also call them multilevel models. I'm not sure what the rest of the question means - perhaps give a concrete example, with a small amount of data.

Comment: I agree with @JeremyMiles it is generally fine to think of these terms as referring to virtually the same model. But I probably should add that some people use these different terms to refer to specific classes of models. When Raudenbush & Bryk discuss "HLMs", they are explicit that they mean mixed models where the random factors are nested, NOT crossed. As for "random effects models," some use this term to refer specifically to mixed models where the only fixed effect is the overall constant term, however, economists often use the term more liberally as essentially a synonym for mixed models.

Comment: thanks so much for the answers. well the HLM was used on count data as DV (taken from firms; IVs are taken from individuals), where he clustered the data into groups. He used R for analyses, and he told me it doesnt matter which level you assign the DV. however, if the analyses (and statistical package used) could be made simpler, can we just use random effects model (regression)?